# Displaying column data by splitting it separately

Tags: php

I am trying to export my data to excel and it is working fine. But i want to change the format or display in php so that i can get the same table format in excel also.

Here is my code

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "<table width='100%' id='ReportTable'>";
echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td width='40%'>".$row['listingsdbelements_field_name']."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row['listingsdbelements_field_value']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
```

now it displays in two columns. But i want the data which are there in `$row['listingsdbelements_field_name']` to be displayed in each column for eg: it contains name1, name2, name3.... these should display like this

```
<tr>
    <td>name1</td>
    <td>name2</td> 
    <td>name3....</td>
</tr>
```

and the values related to these should display under each value.

Can somebody help me in this plz?

*EDITED****

```
echo "<table width='100%' id='ReportTable'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$var = explode('.', $row['listingsdbelements_field_name']);
print_r ($var);
foreach ($var as $value)
{

echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width='40%'>".$value."</td>"; 
}
echo "</tr>";
$var1 = explode('.',$row['listingsdbelements_field_value']);
foreach($var1 as $value1)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" .$value1. "</td>";

}
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

---

```
<table width='100%' id='ReportTable'><tr><td width='40%'>price</td></tr><tr><td>1295000</td></tr><tr><td width='40%'>state</td></tr><tr><td>IL</td></tr><tr><td width='40%'>city</td></tr><tr><td>Chicago</td></tr><tr><td width='40%'>address</td></tr><tr><td>1027 West Chicago Avenue</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: You can use explode function on string to create columns.

Comment: @ Muhammad Zeeshan: if i use explode function, how can i display it in table format. I tried doing explode, but table format display i couldnt do

Comment: explode will return an array, you can loop on that and add <td></td> to your table.

Comment: Muhammad Zeesha: i have edited my code above. I tried like that, still no chance:(. Can you please suggest me where i am doing wrong?

Comment: Whats the length of $var1?? Is it going inside foreach loop??

Comment: yeah, its going inside the loop but not displaying properly

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
echo "<table width='100%' id='ReportTable'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width='40%'>".$row['listingsdbelements_field_name']."</td>";
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['listingsdbelements_field_value']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: @Ing. Michal Hudak: if i do like this , then all the data will be displayed in single column

Comment: Sorry, i did not see it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you were trying:

```
echo "<table width='100%' id='ReportTable'>";                                                                       
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {                                                                         
    echo "<tr>";                                                                                                    

    $var = explode('.', $row['listingsdbelements_field_name']);                                                     
    foreach ($var as $value)                                                                                        
    {                                                                                                               
        echo "<td width='40%'>".$value."</td>";                                                                     
    }                                                                                                               
    echo "</tr>";                                                                                                   
    echo "<tr>";                                                                                                    
    $var1 = explode('.',$row['listingsdbelements_field_value']);                                                    
    foreach($var1 as $value1)                                                                                       
    {                                                                                                               
        echo "<td>" .$value1. "</td>";                                                                              
    }                                                                                                               
    echo "</tr>";                                                                                                   
}                                                                                                                   
echo "</table>";
```

The problem you were having is opening the `<tr>` inside the inner loops, but closing them outside, so you got much more `<tr>` than `</tr>`

Comment: @ Carlos Campderrós: i tried this, still i get the values one after the other, i mean in a single column. :(

Comment: @user2669924 look at the generated source code in your browser and try to find the differences between what's there and what you need

Comment: @ Carlos Campderrós: i have posted the codes which i get when i do view page source... please check above and kindly help me... i have been trying for this from past 3 hrs

Comment: `<tr>` closes everytime, which shouldn't happen